# Showing a modal dialog in blazor client

Tags: bootstrap-4, blazor

I am aware of [Blazored Modal](https://chrissainty.com/blazored-modal-released/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257190/1283836), but I do not  want to have a specific component just for showing modals (lack of flexibility) and want to implement the code in various components myself.

Here is a very simple code to show a sample modal:

```
@page "/fetchdata"


<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => { showModal = true; })">Show Dialog!</button>
@if (showModal)
{
<div class="modal-backdrop fade show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
<hr />

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>


@code {
    bool showModal = false;
}
```

The code works but there is a problem with opacity:
[image]

Putting `style="opacity:1;"` on `<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">` also does not resolve the problem (though giving the `opacity`, values lower than 1 makes it more transparent!)

What is the cause of the problem and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Right click the dialog element and inspect it. Look at the calculated style for the opacity and it will tell you which part of your css is making it semitransparent.

Comment: You can use this Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.Modal/ It supports backdrop and animation as well... Docs: https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/Modal.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use modal-backdrop directly.  Use simply modal.  modal-backdrop is what's applied by the framework to the background content.

Comment: Your suggestion solves the opacity problem of the modal window but how I can make the background darker then (modal-backdrop effect)?

Comment: but an extra div for backdrop
http://blog.ppedv.de/post/Boostrap-Modal-Dialog-fur-Blazor