# How to Show Bootstrap Modal popup on empty Text box in Blazor Server?

Tags: bootstrap-4, blazor-server-side, modalpopup

How to Show Bootstrap Modal popup on empty Text box in Blazor Server?

How to Show Bootstrap Modal popup on empty Text box in Blazor Server?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256798/how-to-use-bootstrap-modal-in-blazor-client-app) which covers this topic. I have tested the accepted solution to this answer and it still works in .NET 6 with Blazor Server App.