# how can we display diff modal for diffrent list of cards in blazor

Tags: blazor

how can we display diff modal for diffrent list of cards in blazor.for insatnce we have 5 cards and onclick it should display modal which is diffrent from the modal if we click card 2. I have tried to do it with creating list and running foreach loop with if conditions , but could not get it right.

[How to use Bootstrap modal in Blazor client app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256798/how-to-use-bootstrap-modal-in-blazor-client-app), i am following some guidelines from here, but could not understand how it will work for a list.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is way too general and un-specified. Can you show some code or describe your problem with more details?