# Bootstrap modal on Blazor stopped working on .NET 8 RC2 (using JSInterop to open/close)

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, .net-8.0, blazor-jsinterop

I believe what I'm doing is against the *dotnet-8-Blazor-way* of doing things, but I'll post anyway as I feel that if more people have done until .NET 7 what I did, this will be useful for them.

Currently (until .NET 8 RC1), I have a page where a bootstrap modal must be opened from C#. To do so, I added two methods (openPOModal, closePOModal) on a JS file and called them from C# using JSInterop:

JS:

```
var selectPOModal = new bootstrap.Modal('#selectPOModal', {
});

var closePOModal = () => {
    selectPOModal.hide();
}

var openPOModal = () => {
    selectPOModal.show();
}

export { closePOModal, openPOModal };
```

Razor component:

```
@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            jsModule = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
                "import", "./Pages/MyComponent.razor.js");
        }
    }

    ...
    private async Task SomethingHappensNeedOpenModal()
    {
        await jsModule.InvokeVoidAsync("openPOModal");
    }
}
```

The modal DOES open even in .NET 8 RC2, but all Blazor controlled elements inside the modal are not responsive anymore.

I have an input inside the modal that is binding to a property and it doesn't get updated anymore. Neither my buttons that call C# methods.

My question is: Is there a simple way to make this work again using JS?

Or is the correct solution to implement bootstrap's open/close logic using Blazor as it's being done in the answers in [this linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59256798/4519548)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have approached this in Blazor .NET 8 RC2 (server) is to add a function to the window that can be called via JS interop.

Firstly, create the function in a JS file that runs on load (in this case using an IIFE).

**my-bootstrap.js**

```
(function() {
  // use a custom namespace to avoid polluting the window object
  window.myNamespace = {
    bootstrap: {
      modals: {
        show: el => {
          // I will be passing in the element itself, 
          // but the selector could also be used
          const instance = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(el);
          instance.show();
        }
      }
    }
  };
})();
```

Create the razor component that contains the modal and an event handler to show the modal via IJSRuntime. In this case I am using a button click.

**my-modal.razor**

```
<button @onclick="@OnButtonClick">Show modal</button>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" @ref="@ModalElement">
    <!-- modal example omitted for brevity, 
         available from the Bootstrap docs -->
</div>

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@code {
    // Get a reference to the rendered element using 
    // the @ref="" syntax on the HTML element
    private ElementReference? ModalElement { get; set; }

    private async Task OnButtonClick()
    {
        // call the function with the element reference 
        // as the first and only argument
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(
            "myNamespace.bootstrap.modals.show", 
            ModalElement);
    }
}
```

I have included a button here simply for demonstration purposes - you can hook into the logic in a way that makes sense for you.

**Edit**

An example of an event handler working from inside the modal:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" @ref="@ModalElement">
    <!-- modal HTML omitted for brevity -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
            @onclick="@OnActionButtonClick">
      Save changes
    </button>  
    <!-- modal HTML omitted for brevity -->         
</div>

@code {
    public async Task OnActionButtonClick()
    {
        // this is working after the modal is displayed
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

It is worth mentioning that I'm using Bootstrap v5.3.2.

Comment: If you place bound inputs or buttons inside that Modal, do they work? Because that's basically the same thing that I have here and mine aren't working after updating to RC2.

Comment: So you are successfully showing the modal, but then Blazor event handlers bound to events triggered from inside the modal don't work? Could you post an example of this. I'll add an edit to the answer to show a working version (on my machine at least ;)) of what I think you're describing.

Comment: I have good and bad news. When creating a simpler example it worked. So I guess it's just my bad code on the full page.